# how to access device local storage folder path in Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I want to download image file from the server to my local storage in some specific folder.
I try that with using Phonegap and it works there with Phonegap using eclipse tool.
I tried that same code in IntelXDK tool as IntelXDK support cordova.
The code as follow

```
function downloadFile(destPath){
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            var uri = encodeURI("imagepath of server");

            fileTransfer.download(
                uri,
                destPath,
                function(entry) {
                    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                },
                function(error) { 
                    alert("download error source " + error.source);
                    alert("download error target " + error.target);
                    alert("upload error code" + error.code);
            });
        }
```

and code to access local storage folder path

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function fail() {
     alert("failed to get filesystem");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
     alert("got filesystem");
     alert(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
}
```

But i am not getting any from `fail()` or `gotFS()` functions

Is there any permission which i am missing to add here. Please provide your comments.
Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys i found the solution. I was trying to access the file system on `deviceReady` function. But we have to call that after device loaded successfully in `load` function.